# mysql shell cannot specify database, showing usage

Tags: mysql, shell, mariadb

```
mysql -hmyhost.com -P12345 -umy_user -pmy_passwd
```

I'm connected, everything is ok.

```
mysql -hmyhost.com -P12345 -umy_user -pmy_passwd my_database
```

mysql shell cannot understand and just show a long Usage

The latter command always fail on my centos, but on another centos I got both 2 commands worked.

Two mysql shell look no difference: "mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.1.9-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1"

Can anyone help ?

Comment: is there no error showing besides the usage information?

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. Try [--database=db_name, -D db_name](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_database).

Comment: @wchiquito with "-D database_name" I can connect to mysql host, but no database selected.

Comment: Are there any punctuation characters in `my_passwd`?

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce the problem. See:

```bsh
$ mysql --version
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.3.11-MariaDB, for linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2

$ mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -P 4557 -u usertest -p -D mysql -A
Enter password:
Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
.
.
.

MariaDB [mysql]>
```

Comment: I have two computers, but only one computer can reproduce this problem. I have no idea which kind of configuration can produce this difference.